# The configuration space of a compact space is not compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a hausdorff connected compact space and let $$C_3(X)=\{(x,y,z)\in X^3\;|\;x\not =y\not =z\}$$
And denote $\Delta$ the complement of $C_3(X)$ in $X^3$.
I read that $C_3(X$ is not compact even if $X$ is compact and I want to understand why? My thought is to show that $C_3(X)$ is not closed in $X^3$ since if it were compact then it would be closed as a subset of a hausdorff space. This can be achieved by showing that its complement $\Delta$ is closed which would imply that $C_3(X)$ is open hence it cann not be open since the only clopen subsets of a connected space is the empty set and the space itself.
Is my reasoning correct or is there a better way to do this ? Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach (showing that the complement of $C_3(X)$ is closed and using connectivity) is correct.

Precisely:

If $C_3(X) = \emptyset$, it is of course compact (i.e. the claim is wrong in that case, e.g. for $|X| = 1$), so let us assume $C_3(X) \neq \emptyset$.

Using the Hausdorff-Property, one can show that $C_3(X)$ is open.

As $X$ is connected, the same is true of $X^3$.

If $C_3(X)$ were compact, it would be closed (as a subset of the Hausdorff space $X^3$). But the only open **and** closed subsets of $X^3$ are $\emptyset$ and $X$.

BTW: Is is intentional that the possibility $x = z$ is not excluded in the definition of $C_3(X)$?

Comment: It is excluded of course: all entries $x,y$ and $z$ are **all** distinct in $C_3(X)$. That is why its complement $\Delta$ is what we call the fat diagonal consisting of entries where at least two of them are equal.

Comment: And by the way I'm talking about only one approach :) I edited the post to be clearer.. and thanks alot for your help..

Comment: Ok, I am talking about "**Then** I thought ...", thats why I wrote "your second approach". If you want all entries to be distinct, you should write $x \neq y \neq z \neq x$. As an additional hint, you have $(C_3(X))^c = \{(x,y,z) \mid x = y\} \cup \{(x,y,z) \mid x = z\} \cup \dots$ (which is a **finite** union). Using the Hausdorff property, it should be easy to see that each of these sets is closed.

Comment: So to show that $\{(x,y,z)|x= y\}$ is closed we can show that $\{(x,y,z)|x\not = y\}$ is open and then we use neighborhoods to separate $x$ and $y$

Comment: Yes. Bonus exercise: Show that the fact that $\{(x,y) \mid x = y\}$ is closed is equivalent to the Hausdorff property.